# Powershell Delete String in text file

Tags: string, powershell, delete-row

I have a file that I am downloading daily what I want to do is create a script that reads the text file and deletes out any lines containing the string "---"

I started with `"(get-content L:\holdings.txt) | where {$_ -ne "" | out-file holdings.txt"`

This deletes all the blank lines without any issue, I then tried

```
$del -like "*-*"
"(get-content L:\holdings.txt) | where {$_ -ne $del | out-file L:\holdings.txt"
```

Which I though would delete out any of the lines of data, whilst it runs without error the line is not being deleted out...

I don't know if it's relevant but the line I want to delete will always be the second line as it is a comma delimited SQL batch file automation.

The file reads as follows

Advice Num          ,Bargain Number
--------------------,-----------------

Just to try and give you a graphical representation that I am trying to resolve

Any ideas?

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 8):

Solved it, a quick amendment and here it is `(get-content "L:\movement.txt") -notmatch "---" | out-file "L:\movement.txt"`

Comment: hope it helps someone else in the future!